# Incomlete type of structure problem with nested structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, structure

I have few problems with structures. Here is my structure block:

```
#define STD_NAME 30
#define COURSE_LIMIT 10
#define COURSE_NAME 50
#define COURSE_CODE 6
#define COURSE_ACRONYM 8

typedef struct {
    int course_id;
    char* course_name[COURSE_NAME];
    char* course_code[COURSE_CODE];
    char* course_acronym[COURSE_ACRONYM];
    int quota;    
}course_t;

typedef struct {
    int std_id;
    char std_name[STD_NAME];
    double std_gpa;
    struct course_t* courses[COURSE_LIMIT]; //nesting part

}student_t;
```

I try to use nested structures and pointers.
For example to get the quota of courses I use simple block in main function like this:

```
int main(void){

   student_t studentProfile;

    for(int i = 0; i < COURSE_LIMIT; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the %d. course quota: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &studentProfile.courses[i]->quota);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile this code, I get an error like:

```
dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct course_t’
         scanf("%d", &studentProfile.courses[i]->quota);
```

I don't know how to fix 'deferencing pointer to incomplete type' because it's little bit confusing with pointers. Should I use memory allocation?

Comment: Did you include the header file that you declared the struct course_t in?

Comment: No I just include stdio and stdlib. I dont think include the header file for course_t is necesarry because I created it in global scope already. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
    int std_id;
    char std_name[STD_NAME];
    double std_gpa;
    struct course_t* courses[COURSE_LIMIT]; //nesting part
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}student_t;
```

At this point there is no such type as `struct course_t`.  There is only  the type `course_t`; they are not interchangeable.

That line should simply be

```
    course_t* courses[COURSE_LIMIT];
```

Comment: You didn't initialize `student_profile.courses[i]` to point to anything, so it's not surprising that you get a segfault when you try to dereference that uninitialized pointer.

Comment: `studentProfile.courses[i]->quota = malloc(sizeof(int));` Is this works?

Comment: No, again you are dereferencing `studentProfile.courses[i]` before pointing it to anything.  I believe you want something more like `studentProfile.courses[i] = malloc(sizeof course_t)`.